# How to manipulate two tables with onclick method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, dom-events, innerhtml

I want to manipulate (add/delete rows) for two tables in html using JavaScript. With one it works, but if I add the second one I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

More precisely: I want to have two tables each with different content based on which button is clicked.

With one table it worked. The first function deleted table content -> added new content. Second function the same, deleted content from first table  -> added its new content.

But I want to do this with two tables. Please let me know how it should be done.

```js
function First(tableID, tableID2) {

  let table = document.getElementById(tableID)
  table.innerHTML = ""; // here is the mentioned error.

  // I would like to have something like..
  // let table2 =  document.getElementById(tableID2)
  // table2.innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<table id="myTable2">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<br>

<button type="button" id="first" onclick="First(myTable, myTable2)">First</button>
<button type="button" id="second" onclick="Second(myTable, myTable2)">Second</button>
```

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wrap `myTable` and `myTable2` in quotations, JavaScript assumes it is an object. Since you didn't define `myTable` nor `myTable2`, they are `null`. You can't modify the `innerHTML` of `null`, and thus you get the error "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

In the example below, the names are wrapped in quotations which makes it a String:

```js
function First(tableID, tableID2) {

  let table = document.getElementById(tableID)
  table.innerHTML = "<tr>first</tr>"; // here is the mentioned error.
  let table2 = document.getElementById(tableID2)
  table2.innerHTML = "<tr>first again</tr>";
}

function Second(tableID, tableID2) {
  let table = document.getElementById(tableID)
  table.innerHTML = "<tr>second</tr>"; // here is the mentioned error.
  let table2 = document.getElementById(tableID2)
  table2.innerHTML = "<tr>second again</tr>";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<table id="myTable2">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<br>

<button type="button" id="first" onclick="First('myTable', 'myTable2')">First</button>
<button type="button" id="second" onclick="Second('myTable', 'myTable2')">Second</button>
```

Alternatively, you could define the two variables before they are referenced:

```js
function First(tableID, tableID2) {

  let table = document.getElementById(tableID)
  table.innerHTML = "<tr>first</tr>"; // here is the mentioned error.
  let table2 = document.getElementById(tableID2)
  table2.innerHTML = "<tr>first again</tr>";
}

function Second(tableID, tableID2) {
  let table = document.getElementById(tableID)
  table.innerHTML = "<tr>second</tr>"; // here is the mentioned error.
  let table2 = document.getElementById(tableID2)
  table2.innerHTML = "<tr>second again</tr>";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<table id="myTable2">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<br>
<script>
  var myTable = 'myTable';
  var myTable2 = 'myTable2';
</script>
<button type="button" id="first" onclick="First(myTable, myTable2)">First</button>
<button type="button" id="second" onclick="Second(myTable, myTable2)">Second</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add some quotation mark on your args when calling your function. Otherwise, javascript think "myTable" is a variable, which doesn't exists.

```
<button type="button" id="first" onclick="First('myTable', 'myTable2')">First</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to use just one function to edit both tables? Here's a version of that. Just pass in the ID of the table with a string.

```js
function eTable(tableID) {
  let table = document.getElementById(tableID)
  let row = table.insertRow(0);
  let cell = row.insertCell(0);
  cell.innerHTML = "New cell for " + tableID;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content</p>
Table 1:
<table id="myTable">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
Table 2:
<table id="myTable2">
  <TR>
  </TR>
</table>
<br>
<button type="button" id="first" onclick="eTable('myTable')">First</button>

<button type="button" id="second" onclick="eTable('myTable2')">Second</button>
```